# React Native Panresponder not behaving correctly when using onLayout from parent view

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Description:

Running this code https://snack.expo.io/@yoobidev/draggable-component on iOS and Android it works as expected.

But if you change line 65 from

`<View style={{ position: "absolute" }}>`

To

`<View onLayout={(e) => console.log(e)} style={{ position: "absolute" }}>`

On android, once you drag an item and drop it, you cannot drag it again. Although it still works fine on iOS.

My dependencies for the project are

```js
{
  "react": "16.9.0",
  "react-native": "0.61.5",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
  "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.29",
  "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
  "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3"
},
```

React Native version:

```
System:
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 41.82 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 11.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
Android SDK:
API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.0, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
```